# Branch permissions for old TFS team project?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If code moved from team project A to team project B, is there a possibility of lingering ManageBranch permissions pointing to project A?

For instance, while trying to branch code in B, I get this error:

```
TF14098: Access Denied: User ______ needs ManageBranch permission(s) for {team project A}.
```

Is this a workspaces issue? How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. As per the error the user needs **ManageBranch** permissions for team project A.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's what I was wondering. Even if it looks like the code isn't attached or related to team project A anymore?

Comment: This is not coming from projectA but instead from projectB. You need ManageBranch on projectB which you do not have.